# What does the jvm option -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=jmap do?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, jmap

I am trying to monitor a process (which crashed due to Out Of Memory) last time on one production machine. The process is running with `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=jmap` option. What does it mean? Does it mean that it would produce a heap dump on OutOfMemory? or the command `jmap` is incomplete and should have more to it?

Answer (score 2):

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError= string` is used to specify a command or script to execute when an `OutOfMemoryError` is first thrown. [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html) is your friend.

Comment: Not very helpful documentation isn't very friendly.

Comment: @StevePowell Not sure what you mean. Documentation describes what commands are available, if you are looking for how to use, then yes it isn't very friendly